# looking for a latex template to compose math contests

Tags: templates

I am composing the problems set of contest for my student, and I am looking for a latex template for this. In particular, I want a template like this http://www.batmath.it/matematica/raccolte_es/ek_competitions/ek_competitions.pdf. Does anyone know what its name?

Comment: this is done using `pdfscreen`. There are many other packages and classes to do presentations in LaTeX though, the most commonly used these days being `beamer`